# Display .u3d file in a webbrowser

Tags: canvas, web, browser, webgl, u3d

Is there a way to display a .u3d file in the browser despite embedding it in a pdf or flash file? May be using Canvas/WebGL?

BR
Chris

Comment: I'm pretty sure three.js has this functionality. http://threejs.org/

Comment: I'm absolutely new to 3D and don't quite understand how a u3d file relates to sth. like threejs. Can I expect sth. like a u3d loader in the framework or how would I open/use such a file with threejs?